# How write a function that sorts and appends to new list?

Tags: python, list, append

I was trying to write some code that will run through a list, unsorted, find the lowest number, than move it to result. It will do this until unsorted becomes empty.  Basically, a sort program.

Did I correctly put the findMin function in a loop in the electionSort function?

How do I take a return value and append it to a new list?

```
unsorted = [4, -9, 10, 2, 3.7, -20, 0]
result = []


def findMin(l):
    l = unsorted
    if len(l) == 0:
        return None
    min = l[0]      
    for i in range (len(l)):   
        if l[i] < min:
            min = l[i]
    return min




def selectionSort():
    for a in range (len(unsorted)):
        findMin(l)
        result.append(min)
    print(result)    

selectionSort()
```

Comment: That won't work.  Before you call findMin, l has no value. Also, you never take any values out of either l or unsorted.

Answer (score 0):

you just need to pass it to `append` function but you need to pass the list as argument to `selectionSort` function too :

```
def selectionSort(l):
    for a in range (len(l)):
        result.append(findMin(l))
    print(result)
```

but still your functions have many problems , you can use this to recipe as a more pythonic way for implement the selectionsort :

**Recursive Selection Sort** :

```
def sel_sort_rec(seq, i):
    if i==0: return       
    max_j = i
    for j in range(i):
        if seq[j] > seq[max_j]: max_j = j
    seq[i], seq[max_j] = seq[max_j], seq[i]
    sel_sort_rec(seq, i-1)
```

**selectionsort** :

```
def sel_sort(seq):
    for i in range(len(seq)-1,0,-1):
       max_j = i
       for j in range(i):
           if seq[j] > seq[max_j]: max_j = j
       seq[i], seq[max_j] = seq[max_j], seq[i]
```

Comment: The output is now, 
[-20, -20, -20, -20, -20, -20, -20]
>>>

Comment: yes its so ! problem is in your function , i will update the answer !

Comment: i edit the answer , but still your selection function have a problem ! you need to define `result` list local in function !

Answer (score 0):

If you are finding the min each time and putting it in a new list, you need to remove that min from the original list before finding another minimum. remove function on a list remove's by value.

```
def selectionSort():
    for a in range (len(unsorted)):
        min = findMin(unsorted)
        result.append(min)
        unsorted.remove(min)
    print(result)
```

Output:

```
[-20, -9, 0, 2, 3.7, 4, 10]
```